# Aggregation Query adjusting dates for timezone

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to run this mongodb query using java code.

Query :

```
db.log.aggregate([
    { $match : { 
        "ts" : { 
            $gte: ISODate("2015-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2015-08-01T18:30:00.000Z")  
        },
        "dup": {$exists:false} 
    }},
    { $project : { 
        'lts': { 
            '$add': ['$ts',5.5*3600*1000]
        }
    }},
    { $group : { 
        _id : { 
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$lts" },
            month: { $month: "$lts" },
            year: { $year: "$lts" }
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```

i have tried with this code but its not worked

```
                                                                                    DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().put("ts").greaterThanEquals(startdate).lessThanEquals(enddate).and("dup").exists(false).get();        
     DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", query); 
     DBObject project=new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("ts",new BasicDBObject("$add",5.5*3600*1000)));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id",new BasicDBObject("day", new BasicDBObject("$dayOfMonth", "$ts"))
    ).append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)));

    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(match,group);

    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
         System.out.println(result);
         }
```

Comment: i have tried with this code but its not worked

Comment: Do you want help or not? Then 1st please understand what code formatting is and also stop undoing the revisions that are trying to clean up your mess. 2nd "Not worked" is not a question. What does not work? Given this came in two parts I can presume you are trying to translate your query into Java and it's not the same.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inital query could have been better written. Presumably you want to group results by "day" whilst also ajusting from UTC to a local timzezone. It usually is better to just stick with the date math rather than mix in the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in such a case, and also this means that the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) here is not required, and you can just go straight to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.log.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
      "ts": { 
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2015-08-01T18:30:00.000Z")  
      },
      "dup": { "$exists": false } 
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$add": [
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$add": [ "$ts", 5.5*1000*60*60 ] },
            new Date(0)
          ]},
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": [
              { "$add": [ "$ts", 5.5*1000*60*60 ] },
              new Date(0)
            ]},
            1000*60*60*24
          ]}
        ]},
        new Date(0)
      ]
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Note the additional `Date(0)` statements in there. This is "epoch" and just like when you [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) a numeric value to a date you get a `Date` type in return, when you [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) you get the integer value. So correcting by adding back "epoch" makes everything a `Date` type again.

Hence the "date math" is employed everywhere, to "round" to a "day":

> ( 1000 millseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours )

And the modulo [**`$mod`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) operator works out the remainder of this which is subtracted from the current date value, to come to the "rounded" date.

All done in `$group` and efficiently as well:

Translating to Java is just following the same indentation:

```
Date startdate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 31, 18, 30, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
Date enddate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 1, 18, 30, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();

DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start()
        .put("ts").greaterThanEquals(startdate)
        .lessThan(enddate)
        .and("dup").exists(false).get();

DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",query);


DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
  new BasicDBObject("_id",
    new BasicDBObject(
      "$add", Arrays.asList(
        new BasicDBObject(
          "$subtract", Arrays.asList(
            new BasicDBObject(
             "$subtract", Arrays.asList(
                new BasicDBObject(
                  "$add",Arrays.asList( "$ts", 5.5*1000*60*60 )
                ),
                new Date(0)
              )
            ),
            new BasicDBObject(
              "$mod", Arrays.asList(
                new BasicDBObject(
                 "$subtract", Arrays.asList(
                    new BasicDBObject(
                      "$add",Arrays.asList( "$ts", 5.5*1000*60*60 )
                    ),
                    new Date(0)
                  )
                ),
                1000*60*60*24
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        new Date(0)
      )
    )
  )
  .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum",1))
);


AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, group));

for ( DBObject result : output.results() ) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Also note that your "timezeone adjustment" here is presuming 5.5 hours "behind" UTC, which I hope is correct. If you mean "after" or positive, then that operation is a "subtraction" and not an addition to correct the UTC hours to days.

So all is good, and your grouping keys are real `Date` objects as well, rather than the composite values returned by date aggregation operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Your solution is excellent. It working fine.   i wanna understand also how can i do it through projection in java if you can help me with that also it will be so great

Answer (score 0):

change field ts to east 8 timezone:

```
    BasicDBObject addEightHour = new BasicDBObject("$add", Arrays.asList( "$ts", 8*1000*60*60 ));
    final BasicDBObject day = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString", new BasicDBObject("format", "\"%Y%m%d\"").append("date", addEightHour));

    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject(
            "value", day));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
```